# Javascript getter methods seems to not work

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods, getter

Hi everyone I've just started javascript recently and I am trying to learn about classes and objects but I ran into a small bump that I could not get through so here is my code

```js
class bubbleSorter{
  constructor(/*params*/){
  //some fields
  }
  #bubbleSorter = () =>{
  //some code
  }

  getBubbleSorter = () =>{
    this.#bubbleSorter();
  }
}

let obj = new bubbleSorter(/*params*/);

console.log(obj.getBubbleSorter());
```

so this is an example of my code.
whenever I try to log the getter method it does not quite work but when I call the bubbleSorter method instead --Assuming I remove the # symbol-- it magically works I do not know why is that happening I tried making bubbleSorter public then calling it inside the getBubbleSorter it still does not work

Comment: Don't use arrow functions as class methods.

Comment: @Barmar how come?

Comment: Because they don't get `this` passed to them, they retain the original `this` from when they were defined.

Comment: `get bubbleSorter() { /*somecode*/ }`

Comment: "*whenever I try to log the getter method it does not quite work*" what do you mean? Your `getBubbleSorter()` method doesn't return anything, so it always implicitly produces `undefined`. That's common behaviour for all functions. If your `#bubbleSorter()` is supposed to return a value, then you need `return this.#bubbleSorter();` inside `getBubbleSorter()`. If it's not that, you need to explain what "doesn't work" means here.

Comment: @Barmar It Still does not work even though i changed it to normal functions

Comment: @Barmar "*they retain the original this from when they were defined*" which would be the object creation, so `this` will point to the created instance. The values should be correct in this case. Unless the constructor swaps out `this` for some other instance. https://jsbin.com/qonudesalu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, right. The linked question is about methods in object, not methods in classes.

Answer (score 0):

`getBubbleSorter` calls `this.#bubbleSorter` but doesn't return the value, causing the function to return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you aren't returning anything in your example. Specifically for

```
getBubbleSorter = () =>{
  this.#bubbleSorter();
}
```

If you change it to

```
getBubbleSorter = () =>{
  return this.#bubbleSorter();
}
```

I think you'll start getting what you expect. What your example currently is doing at the end is the equivalent of

```
console.log(() => {}());
```

right now it's executing a function that has no return value, so it logs out undefined. Once you add that `return` above now you will be logging the result of your private getter.